Requests per second(RPS) not going above certain number with Hana database and Locust
I wanted to perform some load testing on Hana database. For this I decided to use Locust and I referenced the implementation given in this link for another database:
https://community.cratedb.com/t/load-testing-cratedb-using-locust/1686.
Below is the code I rewrote for Hana. I am using a connection pool of size 50 here:
import time
import random
from locust import task, User, between
import os
import json
from datetime import datetime
import uuid
from hdbcli import dbapi
from queue import Queue

# Credentials are always used from here to not have them leak into the UI as
# part of the connection URL.

POOL_SIZE = 50

HOST = ""
PORT = 443  # Default port for HANA DB
USER = ""
PASSWORD = ""

insert_query = f"INSERT INTO DEMO VALUES (?, ?, ?)"


def connect_to_hana():
    """ Connect to SAP HANA database """
    try:
        conn = dbapi.connect(HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD)
        return conn
    except dbapi.Error as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to SAP HANA: {e}")
        return None

connection_pool = Queue(maxsize=POOL_SIZE)

for _ in range(POOL_SIZE):
    conn = connect_to_hana()
    if conn:
        connection_pool.put(conn)


class HANADBClient:
    def __init__(self, host, request_event):
        self._request_event = request_event

    def get_connection(self):
        try:
            return connection_pool.get(block=True)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error getting connection: {e}")
            return None

    def create_conn(self):
        print("Connect and Query HanaSQL")
        return dbapi.connect(
            address="",
            # HANA Host
            port=443,  # HANA Port
            user="",  # HANA User
            password=""  # HANA Password
        )

    def send_query(self):
        request_meta = {
            "request_type": "HANADB",
            "name": "hana insert object",
            "response_length": 0,
            "response": None,
            "context": {},
            "exception": None,
        }

        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        conn = self.get_connection()
        cursor = conn.cursor()


        col1 = random.randint(18, 65)
        col2 = f"Name_{random.randint(1, 1000)}"
        col3 = 5.5

        try:
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            # Generate a batch of records
            cursor.execute(insert_query, (col1, col2, col3))

            conn.commit()

        except dbapi.Error as e:
            print(f"Error inserting object: {e}")
            request_meta["exception"] = e
            conn.rollback()

        finally:
            cursor.close()
            connection_pool.put(conn)

        request_meta["response_time"] = (time.perf_counter() - start_time) * 1000
        request_meta["response_length"] = 1

        # Log a successful insert operation
        self._request_event.fire(**request_meta)


class HANADBUser(User):
    abstract = True

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super().__init__(environment)
        self.client = HANADBClient(self.host, request_event=environment.events.request)


class QuickstartUser(HANADBUser):
    wait_time = between(0, 0)

    @task(1)
    def query01(self):
        self.client.send_query(
        )

When I run the above locust file using this command locust -f benchmark.py --host http://localhost:7997, I see that the Request per second(RPS) never goes above 11 even when I increase the number of users. I was expecting RPS to go till 1000 requests per second.
What could be the issue here?

Hi, have you read the docs on this topic? https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/increasing-request-rate.html
There's also a blog post that might be helpful https://www.locust.cloud/blog/closed-vs-open-workload-models

Specifically it could be an issue with hdbcli not being gevent friendly? You can try an ugly hack which would be launching 50 Locust workers (one for each User instance)

Because you ARE running 50 users, right?

@Cyberwiz I was running it with 100 users. And even tried increasing the number of users.
It could be the case that hdbcli is not gevent friendly but I don't know how to verify this.

that could definitely be it. In general pure python libraries are ok, but C-libraries need to specifically support it. Try running more workers, as a workaround.

@Cyberwiz I was able to increase the RPS but not by much. I used 10 workers with each worker having a pool size of 50. But I was only able to achieve maximum of 80 RPS. This does not improve with increasing the number of workers.

There are some general tips about increasing throughput in Locust here: https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/increasing-request-rate.html Have you checked what's going on on the db side of things?
